# Synchronize two or more database when it goes in online mode with Server

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm going to create an application where many remote machines can record their data in offline mode (in case of unavailability of internet) and when it goes online all the remote machines data will be synchronized with the server database and server will synchronize remote machines. Please suggest how it can be done in SQL server and .Net?

Comment: what's the storage in offline mode? In memory or some kind of file storage?

Comment: Looking to store records in local database in offline mode. remote systems can be shut down, so can't do in memory. whenever remote system goes online want to automatically sync data to server and vice versa.

Comment: Please suggest the right tool.

Comment: I'm not an expert here. I might start from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726002(v=sql.110).aspx.